# Javascript - mapping array of objects undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping

I am passing an object from a function that contains an array `arrCombined`. I have an object titled `results` that I would like to map and remove the strings to so I can convert these strings into an integer. When mapping my array of objects for `results`I am stuck on getting undefined.

Here is my array:

```
[..]
    0: Object { result: "494,927", risk: "LOW", sector: "Online" }
    ​
    1: Object { result: "48,883", risk: "MEDIUM-LOW", sector: "Retail Stores" }
    ​
    2: Object { result: "59,976", risk: "MEDIUM-LOW", sector: "Store Pick up" }
    ​
    3: Object { result: "1,205,915", risk: "MEDIUM", sector: "Drive in" }
    ​
    4: Object { result: "1,434,262", risk: "LOW", sector: "In store" }
```

I am declaring a variable `finalResult` to return the targeted "result" in my mapping function which looks like this.

```
​ let finalResult = arrCombined.arrCombined.result.map(function (e) {
        return Number(e.replace(/(,\s*)+/g, '').trim());
    });

console.log(finalResult) // undefined.
```

I am expecting a `finalResult` to return the result objects as numbers, i.e. `494927, 48883, 59976, 1205915, 1434262`

Comment: Change it to `arrCombined.map(function(e)` and `e.result.replace`

Comment: But, that code should throw: `Uncaught TypeError: e.replace is not a function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take `result` property from each object.

```js
var arrCombined = [
        { result: "494,927", risk: "LOW", sector: "Online" },
        { result: "48,883", risk: "MEDIUM-LOW", sector: "Retail Stores" },
        { result: "59,976", risk: "MEDIUM-LOW", sector: "Store Pick up" },
        { result: "1,205,915", risk: "MEDIUM", sector: "Drive in" },
        { result: "1,434,262", risk: "LOW", sector: "In store" }
    ],
    finalResult = arrCombined.map(({ result }) => Number(result.replace(/(,\s*)+/g, '').trim()));

console.log(finalResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are trying to access `result` property from `arrCombined` which is undefined and thus your code is not working. You simply need to `map` through `arrCombined` and then access `result` property of each object inside array like:

```js
const arrCombined = [
  { result: "494,927", risk: "LOW", sector: "Online" },
  { result: "48,883", risk: "MEDIUM-LOW", sector: "Retail Stores" },
  { result: "59,976", risk: "MEDIUM-LOW", sector: "Store Pick up" },
  { result: "1,205,915", risk: "MEDIUM", sector: "Drive in" },
  { result: "1,434,262", risk: "LOW", sector: "In store" }
]

let finalResult = arrCombined.map(function (e) {
    return Number(e.result.replace(/(,\s*)+/g, '').trim());
});

console.log(finalResult)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this.

```
let finalResult = arrCombined.arrCombined.map(function (e) {
        return Number(e.result.replace(/(,\s*)+/g, '').trim());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It should solve your issue

```js
var arrCombined = [
{ result: "494,927", risk: "LOW", sector: "Online" },
{ result: "48,883", risk: "MEDIUM-LOW", sector: "Retail Stores" },
{ result: "59,976", risk: "MEDIUM-LOW", sector: "Store Pick up" },
{ result: "1,205,915", risk: "MEDIUM", sector: "Drive in" },
{ result: "1,434,262", risk: "LOW", sector: "In store" }
]

var finalResult = arrCombined.map(item => {
  return Number(item.result.replace(/(,\s*)+/g, '').trim())
});

console.log(finalResult)
```